# Erro ao criar um novo arquivo CSV + JavaFx + Windows

Tags: windows, javafx, jar

Bom dia pessoal.
Tenho uma aplicação java desktop(javaFX)que salva alguns dados de configuração em um arquivo CSV.
O jar da mesma funciona perfeitamente tanto no OSX quanto no Linux, porém não no Windows, pelo erro acredito que eu esteja parametrizando de forma incorreta o diretorio, mas não me lembro de outra maneira e nem encontrei(ja tem uns 8 anos que não colocava a mão no Windows).

Segue abaixo código do trecho:

```
Path ARQUIVO_SAIDA = Paths.get("dados.csv");
    private void salvaDados() {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for (Configuracao c : contas) {
        String linha = criaLinha(c);
        sb.append(linha);
        sb.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    }
    try {
        Files.delete(ARQUIVO_SAIDA);
        Files.write(ARQUIVO_SAIDA, sb.toString().getBytes());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

também tentei utilizar o seguinte caminho(no caso acima o arquivo está no mesmo diretorio que o jar)

```
private static final Path ARQUIVO_SAIDA = Paths.get("C:\\PastaSistema\\dados.csv");
```

E retorna o seguinte erro:

> java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: dados.csv
>           at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(Unknown Source)
>           at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newOutputStream(Unknown Source)
>           at java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream(Unknown Source)
>           at java.nio.file.Files.write(Unknown Source)
>           at br.com.denisg.integradorifood.impl.ConfiguracaoServiceImpl.salvaDados
>   (ConfiguracaoServiceImpl.java:81)
>           at br.com.denisg.integradorifood.impl.ConfiguracaoServiceImpl.atualizar(
>   ConfiguracaoServiceImpl.java:51)
>           at br.com.denisg.integradorifood.controller.ConfiguracaoController.atual
>   izar(ConfiguracaoController.java:67)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1771)
>           at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader
>   .java:1657)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Comp
>   ositeEventHandler.java:86)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventH
>   andlerManager.java:238)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventH
>   andlerManager.java:191)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(C
>   ompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDis
>   patcher.java:58)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispat
>   chChainImpl.java:114)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDis
>   patcher.java:56)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispat
>   chChainImpl.java:114)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDis
>   patcher.java:56)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispat
>   chChainImpl.java:114)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
>           at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
>           at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
>           at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
>           at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(Bu
>   ttonBehavior.java:182)
>           at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorS
>   kinBase.java:96)
>           at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorS
>   kinBase.java:89)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.h
>   andleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Comp
>   ositeEventHandler.java:80)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventH
>   andlerManager.java:238)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventH
>   andlerManager.java:191)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(C
>   ompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDis
>   patcher.java:58)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispat
>   chChainImpl.java:114)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDis
>   patcher.java:56)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispat
>   chChainImpl.java:114)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDis
>   patcher.java:56)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispat
>   chChainImpl.java:114)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
>           at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
>           at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
>           at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
>           at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
>           at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
>           at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotificatio
>   n.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
>           at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotificatio
>   n.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEve
>   nt$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
>           at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(Quantum
>   Toolkit.java:389)
>           at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(Glas
>   sViewEventHandler.java:431)
>           at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
>           at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
>           at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
>           at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.ja
>   va:177)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Ja dei permissões nas pastas até com o usuarios Todos e permissão total.
Acredito que seja um erro bem idiota.

Vlww galera